# Rendering MathJax Codes In Chat Rooms With Some iPad Web Browsers

Tags: ios, ipad, web-browser, javascript, latex

## Introduction

For rendering MathJax codes in chat rooms, a JavaScript code has been written in the [installation page](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Erobjohn/math/mathjax.html). This code works perfectly with well-known iPad web browsers such as Safari and Chrome. However, because of some reason I need to run the code in chat rooms with some other browsers such as [this browser](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/browser-file-manager/id475190096) (From now on, I consider this browser as a typical example for the main issue of this post).

## The Main Issue

The browser can render MathJax codes well in the [installation page](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Erobjohn/math/mathjax.html)by tapping the "Start ChatJax" link, so this means that the browser allows JavaScript codes to run. However, after being added to the Bookmarks, the JavaScript code cannot render MathJax codes in chat rooms. So, my question is,

I attempted to solve this as follows. Having observed that the JavaScript code renders MathJax codes well in the [installation page](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Erobjohn/math/mathjax.html) by tapping the "Start ChatJax" link, I guessed that the problem would be resolved by adding the "Start ChatJax" hyperlink in the description of a SE chat room. But, that way could not solve the problem because when you tap any link in a SE chat room, a separate window will be opened.

My question is whether the JavaScript code needs changes or I can effect settings on the iPad
or the browser itself is needed to be improved by its developer?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers#Summary_tables you'll be missing out a very tiny number of users if you can't get it work on the said browser. Also it seems a download oriented browser, not a full fledged one.

Comment: @ankii Thanks for your comment. That mentioned browser is an example of many browsers having the same problem. Other examples: Firefox, Yandex, Edge, ...